# React Hook Form - Don't show error on initial typing, always reporting as invalid

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a form where I want to validate an input upon typing. The input field is required and needs to be between 10 and 100 characters. However, I don't want to show an error upon immediately typing since that would be a bad user experience.

I do however, want to show an error if they've typed up to 11 characters, then backspace to under 10 characters.

```
const MyForm = () => {
    const formMethods = useForm({ mode: 'onChange' })
    const { formState } = formMethods
    const { isValid } = formState

    const [minCharLimitMet, setMinCharLimitMet] = useState(false)

    const onChangeCustom = (e) => {
        if (!minCharLimitMet && e.target.value.length > 10)
            setMinCharLimitMet(true)
    }

    return (
        <FormProvider {...formMethods}>
            <form noValidate onSubmit={...}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    {...register('inputName', {
                        onChange: onChangeCustom,
                        required: true
                        minLength: 10
                        maxLength: 100
                    })}
                />
                {!isValid && minCharLimitMet && <span>Error!</span>}
            </form>
        </FormProvider>
    )
}
```

Basically, I'm keeping track of a variable `minCharLimitMet` and setting it to true once the user crosses the threshold of 10 characters. Therefore, upon initial typing, we won't see an error. Only until they cross the 10 character threshold. If they go back down under the threshold, then we show an error.

However, the `isValid` property is always showing as false for me. It's false upon loading the page, false upon typing, and false upon getting to what should be a valid input.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `mode:` `'onChange'` from the `useForm` options.
2. Use `trigger` to manually validate the field when needed.
3. Use `minCharLimitMet` to control the error display.

`import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useForm, FormProvider, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';

const MyForm = () => {
  const formMethods = useForm();
  const { handleSubmit, formState, control, trigger } = formMethods;
  const { isValid } = formState;
  const [minCharLimitMet, setMinCharLimitMet] = useState(false);

  const onChangeCustom = async (e) => {
    if (!minCharLimitMet && e.target.value.length > 10) {
      setMinCharLimitMet(true);
    }
    await trigger('inputName');
  };

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
   
 <FormProvider {...formMethods}>
      <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Controller
          name="inputName"
          control={control}
          rules={{ required: true, minLength: 10, maxLength: 100 }}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <div>
              <input
                type="text"
                {...field}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  field.onChange(e);
                  onChangeCustom(e);
                }}
              />
              {minCharLimitMet && !isValid && <span>Error!</span>}
            </div>
          )}
        />

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </FormProvider>

  );
};

export default MyForm;`

This code will validate the input when the user crosses the 10-character threshold and display the error message if they go back below the limit.